# Why Blazor CSS isolation not adding the link tag to load the bundled css file?

Tags: blazor

I created a Blazor component and an accompanying css file for the css isolation functionality in the WASM project. When the page is rendered, my element is not getting the css style defined in the css file. Upon inspecting the element, I can see the extra b-* attribute applied to it. I can see a MyProject.Client.styles.css file with the extra b-* added in the css file under ...\obj\Debug\net5.0\scopedcss\bundle\MyProject.Client.styles.css. (* is some random characters)

However, I expected that the Blazor build would add a link tag in the Head section so the browser loads this new bundled css file but it's not there. I used Fiddler and verified that no *.styles.css is being loaded by the browser, which is the problem. Already cleared the cache and application.

Am I missing some manual step or a setting for css isolation to add the link tag? I am using .NET 5.0 release version.

Comment: did you migrate your blazor app from .net core 3.1 to .net 5 ?

Comment: Yes. What's the difference?

Comment: I had this problem too . 
check this [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26464) they will fix this in next update

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add the tag for the bundled CSS file manually to the host page. Blazor does not add this for you.

```
<link href="MyProjectName.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Which file? From which path? This page says Blaxor adds the link for me. https://daveabrock.com/2020/09/10/blazor-css-isolation. MS's page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0 seems to indicate it's added for me. All I see is a MyProject.Client.styles.css deep inside a subfolder in the bin folder.

Comment: The link to the compiled style sheet is only added for you if you create a new .NET5 Blazor project. If you’re upgrading you have to add the link yourself.

Comment: The scoped css file you mentioned in your question. It’s also explained in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#css-isolation-bundling). I have updated my answer with the file as well but for some reason it’s not showing yet.

Comment: The file does not exist. The browser gives a 404 error trying to load that css file. Did you actually try it or are you basing your answer on what you read? I already referenced the page you're referencing. I will try the link mohammadmahdi Talachi mentioned because the link there is actually using the path I mentioned.

Comment: I have noticed, that it's not the project name, but the assembly name `<link href="{ASSEMBLY_NAME}.styles.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: In my case /AssemblyName.styles.css was redirecting to the homepage. I solved it by moving app.UseStaticFiles() before app.UseRouting() in Startup.cs.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bad Idea but this works.
`<link href="@($"{typeof(App).Assembly.GetName().Name}.styles.css")" rel="stylesheet"/>`
Nothing like commenting on a 2 year old answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

I was facing very similar problem in my Blazor Server project based on .NET 6 where I leveraged the [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/) component library. I had to dive a little deeper than the accepted answer.

One of my pages required some tweaks for conditional background colors in a table and I was not able to have my classes from the isolated CSS file applied. After few hours of research on the internet and experimenting with shifting my custom CSS classes from the isolated CSS file to `wwwroot\css\styles.css` in my project folder structure and various placements of the stylesheet link for CSS isolation

`<link href="<MyAssemblyName>.styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

it turned out that the CSS isolation applies **only** to plain HTML, not to Razor components, tag helpers etc. As stated in the [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

> Important: Scoped CSS only applies to HTML elements and not to Razor components or Tag Helpers, including elements with a Tag Helper applied, such as `<input asp-for="..." />`.

The MudBlazor components surely are Razor components and therefore the scoped CSS feature is not supported. I had to keep my custom CSS classes in the `wwwroot\css\styles.css` stylesheet. With that I was able to achieve the look I needed on my pages/components.

In case you **really** need your scoped CSS applied you may try the workaround with the `::deep` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65890644/css-isolation-in-blazor-doesnt-work-with-predefined-form-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly to your question, but I have similar issue, just share here, hope it help.

My project is blazor server app with VS2022, .Net8, it works fine in Dev and Prod Env. After some code refactor, I rename the project name from 'ProjectName' to 'ProjectNameNew'. It still works fine in Dev environment.

However, after I publish it to Prod env, the page displayed with "An unhandled error has occurred. Reload ", the page loaded without any style/formatting.

Chrome's Network shows all file is downloaded, the 'ProjectNameNew.style.css' is also there.

After troubleshooting, find that the 'link tag' in the css file is different between Dev and Prod.

```
.page[b-sx9inz7k4q]
```

Then find there are two *.style.css file in the 'ProjectNameNew\obj\Debug\net8.0\scopedcss\bundle'

```
ProjectName.style.css
ProjectNameNew.style.css
```

Manually delete folder **bin**, and **obj**, rebuild the project, and publish it again to Prod env, all works fine.