# CSS isolation in blazor doesn't work with predefined Form elements

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a page, foo.razor, that represents a Form:

```
<EditForm Model=SomeModel>
    <InputText @bind-Value=SomeModel.Property1 />
    <InputText @bind-Value=SomeModel.Property2 />
    <p>a paragraph</p>
</EditForm>
```

And next to it I have an isolated CSS, foo.razor.css, for example:

```
input{
  display: block;
}
p{
  color: lime;
}
```

The style for the paragraph applies correctly but the style for the input element does not. I can't understand why.

Plus, I know that blazor generates random ids for the elements after compilation. In the browser I can see that the paragraph has such an id but again the input and form elements do not.

I tried adding a class name for the  component and use the deep selector, like this:

```
::deep .classname {
  .......
}
```

But this does not work either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tricky thing about CSS isolation is that it works with plain HTML nodes only, it does not work for components. Under the covers, the elements from your current component that defines isolated CSS get a custom (kind of random) attribute, and CSS rules cascade through that to get scoped to your current component. The framework does not know what is inside other components, through, so it cannot add that attribute to them - their rendering is their own. So, these scoped CSS rules cannot target components.

How to work around that - wrap your components in an HTML element from your current component and write your rules to target elements inside that container too by replacing that element with `::deep`.

Here's an example:

```
input,
::deep input{
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

p,
::deep p {
    color: lime;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

And here's how to modify the form

```
<EditForm Model=SomeModel>
    <div> @* This div right here is the "magic" *@
        <InputText @bind-Value=SomeModel.Property1 />
        <InputText @bind-Value=SomeModel.Property2 />
        <p>a paragraph</p>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code{
    TestModel SomeModel { get; set; } = new TestModel();
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing. Thanks. I also found this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28443) that describes the trick you just mentioned.

Comment: This is a great answer and solved my issues to get a WASM Client component in .net 8 Blazor Server and Client project to see the isolated CSS.
Just add a div tag!

Answer (score 7):

The answer by @rdmptn is correct, but I'll add my two cents anyway. I struggled for a long time to understand and get `::deep` working and I'll just share my journey.

Imagine we'd like to override the color of a `<p>` tag in a child component:

**MyComponent.razor.css**

```
::deep p { color: red !important; }
```

**MyComponent.razor:**

```
<span>My component!</span>
<OtherComponent/>
```

**OtherComponent.razor:**

```
<p>Other component!</p>
```

Now, the generated HTML for **MyComponent.razor** looks something like:

```
<span random1="">My component!</span>
<p random2="">Other component!</p>
```

Every .razor component has a random, unique component-id that gets assigned to all its *plain HTML* tags, i.e. `<div>`, `<p>`, `<span>`, `<img>`, etc. Note how the `<span>` element from **MyComponent** gets tagged with *random1*. And similarly, the `<p>` element gets tagged with *random2* because that element was defined inside **OtherComponent**.

But the generated CSS from **MyComponent.razor.css** looks something like:

```
[random1] p { color: red !important; }
```

That is, the `::deep` CSS selector becomes something like "*all elements of type* `<p>` *under elements with the tag* `random1`". And from the generated HTML above it's clear this will not match the `<p>` from **OtherComponent**. This is why wrapping the content in a `<div>` works:

**MyComponent.razor** (updated)

```
<span>My Component!</span>
<div>
    <OtherComponent/>
</div>
```

And the new generated HTML:

```
<span random1="">My Component!</span>
<div random1="">
  <p random2="">Other component!</p>
</div>
```

And *now* the `::deep` CSS selector will match the `<p>` tag in **OtherComponent**.

Comment: This is really useful, thanks. I was splitting my head as to why my styling doesn't work in same cases, and it was because it was not wrapped in an element but on root razor level.